# Как с помощью map сделать данный перебор?

Tags: javascript

```
let a = [[14, 25, 69], [34, 56], [23, 45, 76, 23, 12]]; 
let a_res;

    const function = () =>{
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < a[i].length; k++) {
                 a_res.push(a[i][k]);
        
           }
    }
```

не помгу понять как ввести третий параметр для перебора внутри каждого из массивов

```
 a_res = a.map(function (num,index){
return num[index]
}
```

Comment: так у тебя твой массив с for не будет работать

Comment: через map - не имеет смысла... через reduce - можно

Comment: Что ожидается получить в результате перебора? Плоский массив?

Comment: Да, мне нужен плоский массив , чтобы провести с каждым элементом умножение

Comment: а если использовать встроенные методы? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Задание просто на Map, вот я по этому спросил у народа , как это сделать, хотя однозначно этот метод не очень хорошо работает с такими массивами. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: map для такой цели не подходит. если это задание дал кто-то - то он балда)